# Access-Control-Allow-Origin какое значение нужно выставить?

Tags: linux, nginx

получаю в консоли такую ошибку

```
Access to fetch at 'https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/26409201?wmode=7&page-url=https%3A%2F%2F...site.ru&t=gdpr(14)clc(0-0-0)rqnt(1)aw(1)ecs(0)fip(1)ti(1)'
from origin 'https://site.ru' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Попробовал через NGINX установить заголовок так

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
```

и

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "no-cors";
```

заголовок сервер устанавливает, но ошибка не уходит, что он от меня хочет? =)

Comment: `mc.yandex.ru` — так заголовок должны устанавливать не вы, а Яндекс